# Не могу понять, как вводить данные строкой c++

Tags: c++

Проблема заключается в вводе двоичного числа. Я не понимаю как ввести это число строкой, а потом закинуть каждый символ в виде числа в массив.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: код в вопросах должен быть представлен в текстовом виде, нажмите под вопросом **Править** и в окне редактирования вставьте код (отступ 4 табуляции считается кодом, на панели есть специальная кнопочка для вставки кода)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну так например:

```
int main()
{
    string s;
    cin >> s; // вводим число строкой
    
    int n = s.size();
    int a[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        if(s[i] == '1')
            a[i] = 1;
        else
            a[i] = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Все заработало